# Display text in button vertically

Tags: html, css

I have a button in my page. How do I display the button text vertically?

```
<div id="btn-toggle-menu">Menu</div>
#btn-toggle-menu {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   width: 20px;
   line-height: 30px;
   cursor: pointer;
   border: 1px solid #333;
   background-color: #ccc;
   text-align: center;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/3/)
I want the "Menu" displayed like this:

```
M
e
n
u
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add breaks between the letters, and then adjust the margin on the `<br />` to tighten up the spacing.

```
<div>M<br />e<br />n<br />u</div>
```

M
e
n
u

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to achieve this is by using `white-space: pre;` or you can use `word-wrap: break-all;`(you will have to fix the width here) as an alternate.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FWzAS/5/)

```
#btn-toggle-menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:20px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/FWzAS/4/

**CSS:-**

```
#btn-toggle-menu {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:13px;
    line-height:30px;
    cursor:pointer;
    border:1px solid #333;
    background-color:#ccc;
    text-align:center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too

```
div#btn-toggle-menu {  
    width: 60px;  
    font-size: 50px;  
    word-wrap: break-word;  
    letter-spacing: 20px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

[**DEMO-1 (Big)**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/QCxmB/) and [**DEMO-2 (Small)**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/QCxmB/1/).